# Cannot resolve reference to bean '__dwrConfiguration'

Tags: spring-mvc, dwr

Iam new to Spring MVC with DWR, Iam facing a problem to integrating the Annotation based spring 3.1 and DWR integrating.
while running my application I got an Exception like:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dwrController': Cannot resolve reference to bean '_*dwrConfiguration' while setting bean property 'configurators' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '*_dwrConfiguration' is defined.
Please help me what does it means.?
on which conditions we get this type of Exceptions.?

commons-logging-1.1.3,dwr.jar,org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.M1.jar.
i have some doubts regarding DWR configurations,*emphasized text*can any one please help me out.
1.What are the dwr/engine.js and dwr/util.js files, and what they do. where do i found, and where do I configure in my spring application. I referred several tutorials, but i didn't get clarify those tutorials, can any one clarify me briefly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aohtthttp://192.168.0.48:16429/CSI/hotelmasterdata.htmp://192.168.0.48:16429/CSI/hotelmasterdata.htmp" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"

Comment: xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">